# How to get the current date in a script using bamboo

Tags: bash, date, bamboo

How can you get the current date in `YYYYMMDD` formate in a `Atlassian Bamboo` script?

Comment: Are you creating a bamboo script or a bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in bash, it's:

```
$ date +Y%m%d
20140815
```

If you want that in a variable, these ways are essentially equivalent:

```
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

It doesn't work for, but

```
DATE=$(date +%%Y%%m%%d)
```

works fine :)
I have Bamboo 3.4.1